# How to display more than one item retrieving data MySQL and Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am currently following a tutorial on retrieving data utilizing an online sql database, volley and android. How ever i am having real trouble making it so that more than one item is displayed. It only displays 1 row of the table even if 5 records match. Any help on this would be much appreciated

I added a loop to the php, which does work if i go through the url.
exampleurl/id="1" displays all correct records in the browser. but im stuck on the java side as it only displays one item

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 $result = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same TextView to override again and again the data:

```
 textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
```

Why don't you use a ListView to show all your results?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Listview or spinner based on your requirement to show more than one item.

```
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
```

after the the above code simply use

```
    JSONObject collegeData;      
    for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
         collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
         name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
         address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
         vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);

         // populate logic here for your spinner or list

    }
```

**Edit**

Initialize below

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

in onCreate() declare the adapter and your ListView

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);
```

Now replace "//populate logic here for your spinner or list" with

```
    dataList.add(name + " " + address + " " vc);
```

After for loop add these line

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Do this and let me know the output. Of course I didn't check this code but it should do the work. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this, what would be the best way to implement a listview in this scenario. I have used listview's and spinners before but with data from an array of strings.

Comment: @uwotm8 : check the Edit section and let me know

Comment: thank you for this. i have implemented this but am having issues with it not displaying. I have updated my op with the implemented method as you suggested

Comment: @uwotm8: I did some minor changes to your code. Now copy paste them appropriately and try to run the code and see.

Comment: still receiving no output from the listview, thank you for the help as always

Comment: Okay i am now receiving output. How ever it is only showing 1 record. The list view looks fantastic, just need to figure out how to get it to show all the records

Comment: @uwotm8: that record you get, is it the last record or the first record of the database table???? Did you set the adapter and notifyDataSetChanged after the for loop parenthesis }???